# Laravel - how to group a Date string on table using collection

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-collection

i want to group my date **Month** but i don't know how to do that. i try used `groupBy()` but its giving me a error

```
$user = Auth::user()->id;
$date = productSold::where('user_id',$user)->get();

$collect = collect($date)->map(function ($date) {
    return date('M',strtotime($date->created_at))->groupBy('created_at');
});
return $collect;
```

error :
Call to a member function groupBy() on string

without groupby this is the output :

```
[
"Oct",
"Oct",
"Nov",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec",
"Dec"
]
```

i want to group `"Oct", "Nov", "Dec"`

Answer (score 1):

Its error because you group by it from a string. So you should take out groupBy statement from map function. So the result should be like :

```
$collect = collect($date)->map(function ($date) {
        return [
            "created_at" => date('M',strtotime($date->created_at))
        ];
    })->groupBy('created_at');
```

The result should be like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkT8i.png).

Comment: how to merge them into a single name like only 3 results. Oct, Nov, Dec

Comment: You want it as string or still an array ?

Comment: already solve my problem. thank you for your effort